# Is there any way for the telegram bot to put emoji on user messages?

Tags: c#, bots, telegram-bot, emoji

I am writing a bot in C# using the Telegram.Bot library. I tried to find information about it in its documentation, but it doesn't say anything about it. Can bots do this? I can provide my code if needed, but there is nothing unusual there. Thanks.

[example of emoji reaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl0HO.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.